# Web part has timed out

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I have a content editor web part on the page which is giving me "Web part has timed out" when it is being viewed through a Live URL

Need help

Comment: can you check the webpart time out setting? do you have any script tie with web part?

Comment: it has only html inside it.

Comment: can you check uls logs ..is there any messge showing there??

Comment: Have resolved the issue? Are are able to find any alternate solution? We are facing same issue on SharePoint online and did not understand the problem. @WaqasSarwarMVP: how to check webpart time out setting?